# Xcode, Simulator: App crashes on launch on older version of Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, version, simulator

I'm having some trouble supporting older versions of iOS. I first noticed this when a buddy of mine was using my app and it crashed. He's running iOS 5 and I'm running iOS 6. I'm building with base SDK 6.0 and I've tried changing the deployment target, the architectures, and pretty much everything I could find and think of. Nothing works and when building on iOS 5 simulator, the app crashes at launch.

I need to fix this so my older version users who download my app aren't experiencing crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using autolayout on any of your `xib` files? By default you would be. If you still are, switch it off.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! Is it possible for me to make two separate views for both the iphone 5 and iphone 4(s) and tell them which devices they are supposed to be viewed on?

Comment: @PerryWaxman If it answered the question, can you kindly accept the answer? It is "possible", but certainly not recommended and better to work without autolayout altogether. Make a single xib. If autosizing (distinct from autolayout) and IB don't give you what you need, subclass UIView and override -awakeFromNib and -layoutSubviews to finish up. Make relative statements, not absolute statements, and use resizable images for buttons etc. and you'll be fine.